# on click of next and previous button component view and title id should change

Tags: angular

I am making product details page in Angular i am getting wrong result on header title its coming on array while clicked on next or previous button my working is:
[image]

> Product-details.component.ts
>       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
>       import { IProduct } from './products';
>       import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
>
> ```
> @Component({
>   templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
> })
> export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
>   pageTitle: string = 'Product Detail';
>   product: IProduct;
>
>   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
>               private router: Router) { }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>    // let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
>   this.route.params.subscribe((params : Params)=>{
>     let id = parseInt(params ['id']);
>     this.pageTitle += `: ${id}`;
>     this.product = {
>       "productId": id,
>       "productName": "Leaf Rake",
>       "productCode": "GDN-0011",
>       "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
>       "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
>       "price": 19.95,
>       "starRating": 3.2,
>       "imageUrl": "assets/images/cutter.jpg"
>     }
>   })  
>   }
>
>   onBack(): void {
>       this.router.navigate(['/products']);
>   }
>   goPrevious(){
>     let previousId = this.product.productId - 1;
>     this.router.navigate(['/products', previousId]);
>   }
>
>   goNext(){
>     let nextId = this.product.productId + 1;
>     this.router.navigate(['/products', nextId]);
>   }
> } Product-details.component.html
>
> <div class="card" *ngIf='product'>
>   <div class="card-header">
>     {{pageTitle + ': ' + product.productName}}
>   </div>
>   <div class='card-body'>
>       <div class='row'>
>         <div class='col-md-8'>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>Name:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.productName}}</div>
>           </div>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>Code:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.productCode | lowercase | convertToSpaces: '-'}}</div>
>           </div>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>Description:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.description}}</div>
>           </div>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>Availability:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.releaseDate}}</div>
>           </div>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>Price:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.price|currency:'USD':'symbol'}}</div>
>           </div>
>           <div class='row'>
>             <div class='col-md-4'>5 Star Rating:</div>
>             <div class='col-md-8'>
>               <pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'>
>               </pm-star>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class='col-md-4'>
>           <img class='center-block img-responsive'
>                [style.width.px]='200'
>                [style.margin.px]='2'
>                [src]='product.imageUrl'
>                [title]='product.productName'>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class='card-footer'>
>       <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary'
>               (click)='onBack()'
>               style='width:80px'>
>         <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i> Back
>       </button>
>
>       <div class="pull-right">
>           <button class='btn btn-danger'
>                   (click)='goPrevious()'
>                   style='width:80px'> Previous
>           </button>
>
>           <button class='btn btn-primary'
>                   (click)='goNext()'
>                   style='width:80px'> Next
>           </button>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

please tell me where i am doing wrong..

Comment: What is the value of wrong results for the header title? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood I hope this the result you are expecting and this answer helps.

```
//Remove the 'Product details here'
pageTitle: string = '';


ngOnInit() {
  // let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.route.params.subscribe((params : Params)=>{
    let id = parseInt(params ['id']);

    //and change the page title like this
    this.pageTitle = `Product details: ${id}`;

    this.product = {
      "productId": id,
      "productName": "Leaf Rake",
      "productCode": "GDN-0011",
      "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
      "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
      "price": 19.95,
      "starRating": 3.2,
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/cutter.jpg"
    }
  })  
}
```

I hope this helps this is what you are expecting! If you need further clarifications let me know!